# Get '~' Abbreviated Path in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path

I came across a problem that I feel should be rather simple, but I cant seem to figure out the answer.

I am trying to abbreviate paths in bash with the '~' similar to how the prompt does.

For example, if I had the path

```
/home/user/temp/file1
```

I would like to turn it into

```
~/temp/file1
```

Is there a simple way to do this? Or am I going to need to figure out how to compare parts of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the current user, you can use the substring substitution operator:

```
$ path=/home/user/foo/bar
$ echo $HOME
/home/user
$ echo ${path/#$HOME/\~}
~/foo/bar
```

For arbitrary users, I don't know of a simple solution.

Comment: The problem with arbitrary users is knowing that you are able to do this and finding the right user. A user's home directory could be *anything* so unless you intend on enumerating every user on the system (which may or may not be possible) and testing every home directory they have you don't have a reliable way of ensuring you do this for all possible cases.

Comment: Ah thank you so much. One thing I did notice though, was that while $HOME works just fine, any subdirectories of $HOME will show the full path. After looking up the substring substitution operator, I believe you can use '#' in place of '%' and it works.

Comment: Sorry about that; I meant to use #.

Comment: For arbitrary user, can we use the fact that the bash would do the `~` expansion...? `path=/home/user/foo/bar; home_other_user=~other_users_username; echo ${path/#$home_other_user/\~}`

Comment: Oh, right. That's... obvious in hindsight :) However, you have to already know the user's name; you can't have the other user's name in a variable.